# I have a form that has a Select element with countries as an option. I want to automate this select element using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a form that has a Select element with countries as an option. I want to automate this select element using Cypress

Want to select each country and submit the form every time.

Dummy HTML

```
<form id="form1">
    <select id="countries">
        <option id="India" value="1">India</option>
        <option id="Nepal" value="2">Nepal</option>
        <option id="Iran" value="3">Iran</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Syntax

Comment: Thanks Dainel, but my question is can we iterate through every option?, I have around 50 countries as options and writing same code for every option and submitting the form will make my script lengthy.is there any way we can use loop here?

Comment: Wrap it in a for loop?

Comment: Are you expecting a different behavior for each option and that is why you need to test each one. If you can achieve this what does your test look like? Do your test involve a backend API where you POST or PUT?

Comment: Perhaps `Cypress.$(#countries option).toArray().forEach(country => { /* test here */ })`

Comment: eric99: thanks for the comments but above code is not selecting the options. And there is bit change in my scenario, now i have to select option/countries based on the region. for example,suppose i have select element with option containing countries from different region like Asia, Europe etc so how to select them one by one